# Protractor: getting cookie value returns object instead of the cookie values

Tags: cookies, protractor

Using Protractor to check cookie contents I get in console output `[object Object]` instead of values.

I'm using the following to get the cookie values written in the console output:

```
browser.manage().getCookie('_session_cookie').then(function(cookie) {
        console.log(cookie);
});
```

I even tried, but got more object text as an output:

```
browser.manage().getCookies().then(function(cookies) {
            console.log(cookies);
});
```

Am I not seeing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `getCookie` and `getCookies` return a JSON object, so this seems to be working correctly. Try using `console.dir()` to print out the object.

```
browser.manage().getCookies().then(function(cookies) {
    console.dir(cookies);
});
```